# Encrypt data on client, and then decrypt on-chain?

Tags: data, encryption

Is there support for encrypting data on client-side (ideally with public key of the program that owns the on-chain program), storing such data on chain, and then **decrypting** it **on-chain** when the transaction is fired?

Comment: This might be helpful for you: https://twitter.com/bigtimetapin/status/1562146360035422208?s=20&t=pUziNihp_B7YY3Afy1VOxg